# What is an annotated dataframe really?

Tags: r, class, bioconductor

I'm a new SO user but also new(-ish) at R. I've recently encountered annotated dataframes. I've tried to do my due diligence in searching for a good explanation and I have read the following about Annotated DataFrames https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Biobase/versions/2.32.0/topics/AnnotatedDataFrame. But I don't get what an AnnotatedDataFrame is.

Is it effectively a list of two dataframes (one metadata and the other data)?

Apologies for the annoying question, but it's not clear to me what I'm working with. Any clarification is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *"Is it effectively a list of two dataframes?"* No, it is not. Bioconductor uses S4 classes, not S3 (objects of class `"list"`). To see what is in your AnnotatedDataFrame, use `str(obj)`. But Bioconductor is a world in itself and you will probably need some time to get acquainted to it, this is not a question that can be answered in only a few words.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I've seen S3 and S4 classes before but wasn't sure what that meant or how that relates to the data structures I'm used to seeing. Knowing that I should expect differences helps. Also, I wasn't aware that Bioconductor is, as you said, "a world in itself." Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as you have read the documentation,

> Description. An AnnotatedDataFrame consists of two parts. There is a
> collection of samples and the values of variables measured on those
> samples. There is also a description of each variable measured. The
> components of an AnnotatedDataFrame can be accessed with pData and
> varMetadata .

Annotation-dataframe is basically the concept we use in data manipulation, I mention an example and I hope it will get clear for you.

Imagine you have 10 articles(of a website) and you want to do analysis on them, like finding how many nouns are used for each word in each article, how many adjectives and so on. so first you separate each word from articles and put them in their designated rows, then what? then you have a list of words but you need to map them to a field that works as meta so that you can run a trained machine learning model on those to know which words are what, in preparation of doing that you need to convert your data into a data that is now annotated which we call Annotated-Dataframe.